# ¿Cómo grafico un polinomio de Newton en Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy tratando de graifcar un polinomio muy largo en Matplotlib y me salta 
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable "

Este es mi código:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

def polinomioNewton(x0):
    return (-1022.845661 + 9926.9675371 (x0- 0.1 )+ -48121.351633555 *(x0- 

0.1 )*(x0- 0.2 )+ 155972.42033554998(x0- 0.1 )*(x0- 0.2 )*(x0- 0.3 )+ -380051.1258764999 *(x0- 0.1 )*(x0- 0.2 )*(x0- 0.3 )*(x0- 0.4 )+ 742278.0479866666 *(x0- 0.1 )*(x0- 0.2 )*(x0- 0.3 )*(x0- 0.4 )*(x0- 0.5 )+ -1210083.3117451388*(x0- 0.1 )*(x0- 0.2 )*(x0- 0.3 )*(x0- 0.4 )*(x0- 0.5 )*(x0- 0.6 ) etc

# Valores del eje X que toma el gráfico.
x = range(-10,10)
# Graficar ambas funciones.
pyplot.plot(x, [polinomioNewton(i) for i in x])
#pyplot.plot(x, [f2(i) for i in x])
# Establecer el color de los ejes.
pyplot.axhline(0, color="black")
pyplot.axvline(0, color="black")
# Limitar los valores de los ejes.
pyplot.xlim(-10, 10)
pyplot.ylim(-10, 10)
# Guardar gráfico como imágen PNG.
pyplot.savefig("output.png")
# Mostrarlo.
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Y ese etc que está al final de esa línea larguísima?  Tal vez dar un formato apropiado a tu código te ayude a tener la solución. Es más, siendo python la falta de formato podría ser en sí el problema.

Comment: cambia `... +  9926.9675371 (x0- 0.1 ) + ...` a `... +  9926.9675371*(x0- 0.1 ) + ...`, ademas provee un [mre]

Comment: Lo terminé escribiendo como columnas para no perder de vista cada término y funcionó. El problema era que uno de los términos no estaba multiplicado (faltaba un *)

Comment: @DarkStormSeeker: por favor edita el código del post poniendo la fórmula correcta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos problemas con el código:

- Expresiones como `9926.9675371 (x0 - 0.1)` necesitan una multiplicación explicita: `9926.9675371 * (x0 - 0.1)`.
- Al poner `pyplot.ylim(-10, 10)` mientras `y` en realidad tiene valores como `-1576660977004.1`, no se puede ver nada interesante en la ventana de -10 a 10. Seria mucho mejor dejar matplotlib mismo eligir los valores de `ylim` (quitando la llamada a `pyplot.ylim`).

Otra cosita:

- `x = range(-10,10)` solo da 20 valores para `x`. Mejor emplear `linspace` de `numpy` para poner más valores.

El código quedaria como:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
'''
def polinomioNewton(x0):
    return (-1022.845661 + 9926.9675371 * (x0 - 0.1) + -48121.351633555 * (x0 - 0.1) * (
                x0 - 0.2) + 155972.42033554998 * (x0 - 0.1) * (x0 - 0.2) * (x0 - 0.3) + -380051.1258764999 * (
                        x0 - 0.1) * (x0 - 0.2) * (x0 - 0.3) * (x0 - 0.4) + 742278.0479866666 * (x0 - 0.1) * (
                        x0 - 0.2) * (x0 - 0.3) * (x0 - 0.4) * (x0 - 0.5) + -1210083.3117451388 * (x0 - 0.1) * (
                        x0 - 0.2) * (x0 - 0.3) * (x0 - 0.4) * (x0 - 0.5) * (x0 - 0.6))
'''


def polinomioNewton(x0):
    return (-1022.845661 + 9926.9675371 * (x0 - 0.1) + -48121.351633555 * (x0 - 0.1) * (
                x0 - 0.2) + 155972.42033554998 * (x0 - 0.1) * (x0 - 0.2) * (x0 - 0.3) + -380051.1258764999 * (
                        x0 - 0.1) * (x0 - 0.2) * (x0 - 0.3) * (x0 - 0.4) + 742278.0479866666 * (x0 - 0.1) * (
                        x0 - 0.2) * (x0 - 0.3) * (x0 - 0.4) * (x0 - 0.5) + -1210083.3117451388 * (x0 - 0.1) * (
                        x0 - 0.2) * (x0 - 0.3) * (x0 - 0.4) * (x0 - 0.5) * (x0 - 0.6))

# Valores del eje X que toma el gráfico.
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 50)  # 50 valores x entre -10 y 10
#x = range(-10, 10)
# Graficar ambas funciones.
plt.plot(x,  [polinomioNewton(i) for i in x])
# Establecer el color de los ejes.
plt.axhline(0, color="black")
plt.axvline(0, color="black")
# Limitar los valores de los ejes.
# plt.xlim(-10, 10) # eso matplotlib ya hace automático
# plt.ylim(-10, 10) # mejor no
# Mostrarlo.
plt.show()
```

Nota el `1e12` en el eje `y`: valores entre `-1.6e12` y `0`.
[image: el plot]

PD: Con el modulo `sympy` se puede simplificar las expresiones:

```
from sympy import symbols

x0 = symbols('x0')
expr = (-1022.845661 + 9926.9675371 * (x0 - 0.1) + -48121.351633555 * (x0 - 0.1) * (
                x0 - 0.2) + 155972.42033554998 * (x0 - 0.1) * (x0 - 0.2) * (x0 - 0.3) + -380051.1258764999 * (
                        x0 - 0.1) * (x0 - 0.2) * (x0 - 0.3) * (x0 - 0.4) + 742278.0479866666 * (x0 - 0.1) * (
                        x0 - 0.2) * (x0 - 0.3) * (x0 - 0.4) * (x0 - 0.5) + -1210083.3117451388 * (x0 - 0.1) * (
                        x0 - 0.2) * (x0 - 0.3) * (x0 - 0.4) * (x0 - 0.5) * (x0 - 0.6))
print(expr.simplify())

# resultado:
-1210083.31174514*x0**6 + 3283453.00265146*x0**5 - 3611113.99341049*x0**4 + 2056371.12113339*x0**3 - 638252.78851607*x0**2 + 102207.183691921*x0 - 6587.9203135385
```